# Mac OSX can't repair the disk "ExFat"

Tags: windows, snow-leopard

The drive works fine on Windows and Linux but gives me this error in OSX?

[image]

Is there a reason?  Maybe something to run in either Windows or OSX to fix this?

It is an external drive I could try plugging directly in to see what it does although I haven't decided if that is a good idea. It is regular HDD not SSD. It will not let me repair disk permissions.

Possible related questions:

- [How can I repair a disk that Disk Utility says it can't repair?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130304/how-can-i-repair-a-disk-that-disk-utility-says-it-cant-repair)
- [Disable the disk check when reconnecting an improperly disconnected disk to OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230698/disable-the-disk-check-when-reconnecting-an-improperly-disconnected-disk-to-os-x)
- [Why is exFAT so slow on Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56872/why-is-exfat-so-slow-on-mac/87318?noredirect=1#comment348004_87318)

Comment: Please tell us more about the disk! Is it internal or external? HDD, SSD or thumb drive? What have your tried to fix it (repairing disk or permissions, etc)? Please be as detailed as you can

Comment: @NoahL hmm external I could try plugging directly in to see what it does.  HDD.  It will not let me repair disk permissions.

Comment: Before you do anything, make sure you have a backup of it (either on Mac or PC)

Comment: Btw, you can only repair permissions on a boot drive.  Any other drive you can just set to ignore, Get Info on the drive itself to disable.

Comment: @Tetsujin how do I ignore this issue?  Windows and linux are okay with the drive.

Comment: You can't ignore the issue itself; I'm just saying that there is no option to repair permissions on an external drive & you can set to ignore instead.

Comment: @Tetsujin would that fix the issue though?  Repairing permissions.  I have a mac pro which allows me to hook up hard drives.

Comment: Permissions is a red herring. Forget it. You cannot repair permissions on anything other than a boot drive :/ Permissions is not your problem. "It will not let me repair disk permissions."... Correct, it won't.

Comment: @Tetsujin what about repair disk?

Comment: Do exactly what the error message said - backup the data & reformat.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have been using the drive less then a week I do not plan to do this because it works fine in Windows.